# How to display content on hovering of a particular hovering card in vue.js?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have one component which is responsible for displaying books and the response is coming from backend upto this it's working fine,Now what i need is when i hover on any particular card i want to display BOOK description [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd6po.png) (this key also present in response which is coming from backend).How to acheive this thing please help me to fix this issue....

`DisplayBooks.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="card book">
        <div class="image-section">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img  v-bind:src="book.file" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title-section">
            {{book.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="author-section">
            by {{book.author}}
        </div>
        <div class="price-section">
            Rs. {{book.price}}<label class="default">(2000)</label>
           
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            {{book.description}}
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="button-groups"  v-if="!addedBooks.includes(book.id)">
                <button type="submit"  @click="handleCart(book.id);toggle(book.id);addedBooks.push(book.id)"  class="AddBag">Add to Bag</button>
                <button  class="wishlist">wishlist</button>
            </div>
            <div class="AddedBag" v-else>
            <button class="big-btn" @click="removeFromCart(book.id);addedBooks=addedBooks.filter(id=>id!==book.id)">Added to Bag</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
      mounted() {
            service.userDisplayBooks().then(response => {  
                this.books.push(...response.data); 
                return response; 
            })
        },
    data() {
        return {
            isActive:true,
            result: 0,
            authorPrefix: 'by',
            pricePrefix: 'Rs.',
            defaultStrikePrice: '(2000)',
            buttonValue: 'Add to Bag',
            buttonWishlist:'wishlist',
            buttonAddedBag:'Added to Bag',
            flag: true,
            state: true,
            addedBooks:[],
            clickedCard: '',
            books: [
          
            ]
        }
    },
    watch:{
    addedBooks:{
            handler(val){
               this.$emit('update-books-count',val.length)
             },
             deep:true
          }
        },
    methods: {
        toggleClass: function(event){
            this.isActive = !this.isActive;
            return event;
        },
         toggle(id) {
            this.clickedCard = id;
            console.log(this.clickedCard);
          
        },
        flip() {
            this.state = !this.state;
        },
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
  
        handleCart(bookId){
            let userData={
                id: bookId,
            }
            service.userUpdateCart(userData).then(response=>{
                return response;
            }).catch(error=>{
                alert("error while displaying Books");
                return error;
            })
        },
        removeFromCart(bookId){
            let userData={
                id:bookId,
            }
            service.userRemoveFromCart(userData).then(response=>{
                return response;
            }).catch(error=>{
                alert("error while removing from cart");
                return error;
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
   @import "colors";
.carddisplay-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-around;
    gap: 10px;
}
.card:hover{
    box-shadow:0.6px 0.6px 0.6px 0.6px rgb(173, 206, 206);
}
.card {
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    background:$pink;
    width: 235px;
    height: 315px;
    background: $pale_white 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border: 1px solid $border_clr;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.image-section {
    width: 233px;
    height: 172px;
    background: #F5F5F5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}

img{
    margin-left: 67px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    width: 105px;
    height: 135px;
    opacity: 1;
    border:none;
}

.title-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/19px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 19px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.author-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal normal 13px/13px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_grey;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 123px;
    height: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.price-section {
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 12px/16px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_black;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;

}

label {
    text-decoration-line: line-through;
    font: normal normal normal 10px/13px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $light_grey;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 36px;
    height: 13px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.price-section button[type="submit"] {
    border: none;
    padding-left: 65px;
    background: none;
    font-size: 15;
}
.button-groups{
    display:flex;
    margin-top:8px;
}
.AddBag{
    background: $redish_brown 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 93px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color: $pale_white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: small;
}
.wishlist{
    margin-left:4px;
    color: $pale_white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: small;
    border: 1px solid #7c7a7a;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: $light_black;
    width:93px;
}
.big-btn{
    width: 191px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-left:20px;
    background: #3371B5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
    color:$pale_white;
    margin-top:8px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define additional flag inside `book` object. Let call it `hover`.

You would have to attach this property to your books after your data came back from the backend.
For example like this using simple `map`:

```js
mounted() {
    service.userDisplayBooks().then(response => { 
        let data = response.data;
        data.map(function(obj) {
            obj.hover = false;
            return obj;
        });

        this.books.push(...data); 
        return response; 
    })
},
```

Or in more consise manner using `Object.assign`:

```js
mounted() {
    service.userDisplayBooks().then(response => { 
        this.books.push(Object.assign(...response.data, {hover:false}));
        return response; 
    })
},
```

Then, to check whether someone hovered over a book you could use `@mouseover` and `@mouseleave` like this:

```html
<div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" 
     class="card book" 
     @mouseover="book.hover = true"
     @mouseleave="book.hover = false">
```

There is also an option of doing this without initializing `hover` flag beforehand. You could use a way suggested by Lawrence in the comments.

```html
<div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" 
     class="card book" 
     @mouseover="$set(book, 'hover', true)"
     @mouseleave="$delete(book, 'hover')">
```

Lastly you could just add `v-if` inside description:

```html
<div class="description" v-if="book.hover">
```

By doing so this `div` with description would show only after someone hovered over a book.

Comment: From backend i am not getting any hover:false, How to add this one because i am getting dynamic content

Comment: You could do this in many different ways. Solution provided by Lawerence will work. You could also use simple `map` to add this property to every book. Please check edited answer.